# How to effectively use available RAM with Dask

Tags: parallel-processing, computer-science, dask, ram

I am trying to use my works remote desktop to run a fairly computational script.

I was trying to understand how to effectively used chunking so to not run out of available RAM. I did run out and it started to write some of the information in memory to disk. I had to shut it down.

But my question is:

Can chunking make a difference or is it just a result of having such a large dataset which needs to be processed?

The code is below with a snippet of the dask status.

```
# Define the chunk size for each dimension
chunk_size = {'Time':262968 ,'south_north': 20, 'west_east': 20}

# Chunk the dataset using Dask
ds_chunked = ds.chunk(chunk_size)

# Perform the calculation for each chunk (now in a lazy manner)
ws = np.sqrt(np.square(ds_chunked.U) + np.square(ds_chunked.V))
WH = np.ceil(ws * 2) / 2
WL = np.floor(ws * 2) / 2
Rho_H = (np.ceil(ds_chunked.RHO * 40) / 40)
Rho_L = (np.floor(ds_chunked.RHO * 40) / 40)

WH= WH.where(WH > 3.0, 0)
WH= WH.where(WH<24.5,24.5)

WL= WL.where(WL > 3, 0)
WL= WL.where(WL<24.5,24.5)

Rho_L= Rho_L.where(Rho_L > 0.95, 0.95)
Rho_L= Rho_L.where(Rho_L< 1.275, 1.275)

Rho_L=Rho_L.astype(str)

# Assuming da is already defined and it's a lookup table
power = da.sel(row=WH, column=Rho_L)
power = (power / 2)
power.name = 'Power_Curve'
power_curve_dataset = power.to_dataset()

# Save the chunk to a single zarr file
power_curve_dataset.to_zarr("S://VESTAS_V150_processed_power_dataset", mode='w')
```

[image: Dask Status]

Answer (score 0):

as a rule of thumb, chunk size directly influences the heap for your currently running tasks. It should be >> than the number of your threads. A good rule-of-thumb is to make sure your chunks are somewhere between 50 and 250 MB each.

Symptoms of chunks too large:

- excessive amounts of unmanaged memory while the tasks run
- some workers are busy for long periods of time, while others are idle
- managed memory is unnecessarily

Symptoms of chunks too small:

- GIL contention
- lots of time needed to submit computations
- high CPU load on the scheduler (if it reaches 100%, the whole cluster will slow down)